# Integrate Video.js to the non-HTML5 page

Tags: html, html5-video, flash-video

Is it possible to install [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) player to the non-HTML5 page (e.g. HTML 4.01 Strict)? i.e. to use HTML5 functionality without actually using HTML5 doctype. What is the best way to do this? What complications or problems it can cause if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 functionality isn't reliant on the doc type of the site you're visiting, but rather on the browser that is displaying the page. If you insert an HTML5 tag ("video", "article", etc) into a page with the html 4.01 strict doc type, it will display properly provided the browser understands the tag in question.